# Ionic 2 - Use ios action sheet style for android

Tags: ionic2

I'm doing some forms on my app and checking the ion-select component (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/), I realized that the ios version looks better than the android version. Is there a easy way to change the behavior so I can use the ios style on android/browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, We can use select options for this. Take a look of the following code.

```
 this.selectOptions = {
        title: 'Pizza Toppings',
        subTitle: 'Select your toppings',
        mode: 'ios' // here we can specify our required platform
 };
```